# How can one provide custom compiler/linker flags for OpenSSL?

Tags: linux, gcc, build, openssl

I'm trying to build OpenSSL with -Wa,--noexecstack, but can't find anywhere in its config command-line to provide this flag.  I've tried to set CFLAGS, but it appears to ignore that and just use its own.

This is an automated build working off a clean copy of the OpenSSL source, so a one-time hack of the config script isn't really an option.

Is there a way to pass custom flags to OpenSSL's build process?

Comment: Note that the documentation actually suggests that you do those edits you'd like to avoid - see https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Modifying_Build_Settings, where they talk about running sed as part of your build.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `config` script ignores `CFLAGS`, but not `CC`.  So you can specify your compiler and give it the flags at the same time:

```
export CC="gcc -Wall -DHELLO_WORLD"; ./config
```

Alternatively, since `config` auto detects your platform and then runs `Configure` with preset compiler settings, you can add the compiler flags to your platform configuration.  E.g., for my mac, I see this line when I first run `config`:

```
Operating system: i386-apple-darwinDarwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun 7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
Configuring for darwin-i386-cc
```

So if I open `Configure`, I can search for `darwin-i386-cc` and add the flags to the presets.

If you're not using a preset configuration, then you'd just pass the flags directly to `Configure` on the command line and it'll use them.

Answer (score 21):

Later to the party, but this seems to be the correct way of doing this.

From the `config` script help:

```
$ ./config -h
Usage: config [options]
 -d Add a debug- prefix to machine choice.
 -t Test mode, do not run the Configure perl script.
 -h This help.

Any other text will be passed to the Configure perl script.
See INSTALL for instructions.
```

So the `config` script forwards "unexpected" options to the `Configure` script. Well, lets see what the `Configure` script has to say about that:

```
$ ./Configure --help
Usage: Configure [no-<cipher> ...] [enable-<cipher> ...] [experimental-<cipher> ...] [-Dxxx] [-lxxx] [-Lxxx] [-fxxx] [-Kxxx] [no-hw-xxx|no-hw] [[no-]threads] [[no-]shared] [[no-]zlib|zlib-dynamic] [no-asm] [no-dso] [no-krb5] [386] [--prefix=DIR] [--openssldir=OPENSSLDIR] [--with-xxx[=vvv]] [--test-sanity] os/compiler[:flags]
```

See the `[:flags]` part at the end of that long line? There is also a comment inside the file:

```
# -<xxx> +<xxx> compiler options are passed through
```

It's not that obvious since it does not follow well known standards but the answer is: just append the options to the end of the `config` command line.

As a long time has passed since you posted the question, I must add:

- it may not work for the version of OpenSSL you are working with (mine is OpenSSL 1.0);
- I felt compelled to post this answer since none of the previous answers solved my problem and it took me a little while to figure out that solution.

Comment: Turns out this isn't useful.  Most of the time you're going to need to _set_ cflags; this just appends them.  Doesn't help get rid of bad ones that are there already.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work with all types of flags. For example on Windows, there is no way to set "/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,x.xx" and you still have to fall back to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248464/423913).

Answer (score 5):

Late to the party, but another way of doing this is to make an automated edit to the generated makefile.  E.g., to add `-DPURIFY` to the flags, I first do the regular configure, then:

```
perl -i~ -plwe 's!^(CFLAG=.*$)!$1 -DPURIFY!' Makefile
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works for me.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to remove or replace a flag.

Answer (score 0):

1. CC=clang ./config [other args]
2. CC=gcc ./confug [other args]

etc